# spring jdbc : simplejdbcall doesn't read metadata for parameters when executing stored procedure using synonym

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to execute a stored procedure using simpleJDBCCall.excute(in) method but it doesn't read the metadata in case of using synonym for the procedure.

Here is the code.

```
SimpleJdbcCall optOutCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
        .withSchemaName("USER_SCH")
        .withCatalogName("USER")
        .withProcedureName(ADD_ADDRESS) 
        .declareParameters(
                new SqlOutParameter("returnCode", Types.NUMERIC),
                new SqlParameter("product_id", Types.NUMERIC),
                new SqlParameter("user_id", Types.NUMERIC),
                new SqlParameter("email_address", Types.VARCHAR));
    long returnCode = 0;
    inputs.addValue("returnCode", returnCode);
    inputs.addValue("product_id", 1);
    inputs.addValue("user_id", 45673);
    inputs.addValue("email_address", "a.b@abc.com");

    optOutCall.execute(inputs);
```

Here "***ADD_ADDRESS***" procedure exist under "***USER***" package in a schema called "***USER_DATA***". I have created a synonym for the same package/procedure in another schema called "***USER_SCH***". when i execute the code using simpleJDBCCall.execute() method it doesn't read the metatadata and throws the following execption.

```
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD_ADDRESS'ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Here are the log messages.

```
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,019] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall]: [JdbcCall call not compiled before execution - invoking compile]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,019] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils]: [Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,020] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory]: [Using org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.OracleCallMetaDataProvider]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,020] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProvider]: [Retrieving metadata for USER/USER_SCH/ADD_ADDRESS]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,028] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils]: [Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,028] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall]: [Compiled stored procedure. Call string is [{call USER.ADD_ADDRESS()}]]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,028] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall]: [SqlCall for procedure [ADD_ADDRESS] compiled]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,028] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext]: [Matching [returnCode, product_id, user_id,email_address] with []]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,028] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext]: [Found match for []]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,028] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall]: [The following parameters are used for call {call USER.ADD_ADDRESS()} with: {}]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,028] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: [Calling stored procedure [{call USER.ADD_ADDRESS()}]]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,028] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils]: [Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,034] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils]: [Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,034] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory]: [Looking up default SQLErrorCodes for DataSource [weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource@2521ddb8]]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,034] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory]: [SQLErrorCodes found in cache for DataSource [weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource@2521ddb8]]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,035] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator]: [Unable to translate SQLException with Error code '6550', will now try the fallback translator]
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,035] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator]: [Extracted SQL state class '65' from value '65000']
[07 Oct 2014 10:32:49,035] [ WARN] [gproducterr]: [Handler execution resulted in exception]
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call USER.ADD_ADDRESS()}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD_ADDRESS'ORA-06550: line 1, column :PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

But if i execute the same code with schema name "USER_DATA" where this procedure "USER.ADD_ADDRESS" exists then it reads the metadata information correctly and executes the procedure.

user that i am using has the execute permissions for "USER_SCH.USER.ADD_ADDRESS" procedure.

what change do i need to make to read the metadata correctly when executing any procedure using synonyms??

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 9):

Add ".withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();". It will stop spring to read jdbc metadata and will use the details provided by you. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a synonym for a packaged procedure/function. You can create synonyms for:

- Table or object table
- View or object view
- Sequence
- Stored procedure, function, or package
- Materialized view
- Java class schema object
- User-defined object type
- Synonym

Thus, you can create a synonym for the package but you'll still need to refer to the procedures/functions/whatever within the package by their declared name.

[Reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7001.htm#CJAJCDDF)

Share and enjoy.